# Project Template to be placed under "Test Projects" Node

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I have created a project template that comes under the node 'CSharp'.

What changes i should make to .vstemplate file or any other files such that i can place my Template under "Test Projects" Node (5th Node in the list shown below.)..??!

> In Visual Studio 2010 (where following Nodes exist in New Project
>   Dialog)
>
> Visual C#
>
> Other Languages
>
> Other Project Types
>
> Database
>
> Test Projects -- My project Template to come under this node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this by Creating custom projects [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165083.aspx).